Does SpringBoot Caching have a mechanism to use Redis Key and Field Name
Does Spring Boot Cache have a mechanism to use Redis field names, such as have a method to save all of the fields, another to save only one of the fields, and one to get back all of the fields, e.g.
class BookService {
   @Cacheable(value="books" key="???")
   Book getBook(String author, String isbn) {
      ...
   }

   @Cacheable(value="books" key="#author")
   Map<String, Book> getBooks(String author) {
      ...
   }

   /* 
     Save the map of isbns to books under the author key 
    */
   @CachePut(value="books" key="#author")
   void saveBooks(String author, Map<String, Book> books) {
      ...
   }

   /* 
     Save a single isbn field to a book under the author key
    */
   @CachePut(value="books" key="???")
   void saveBook(String author, String isbn, Book book) {
      ...
   }

